# Use Windows Server 2012 R2 IPAM Role to Manage a DHCP Cluster

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server, windows-cluster, ipam

My Google-fu is failing me today. I would like to blame the bad office coffee, the fact that it is a Monday, and the lack of information online...but maybe it is my fault. Either way, I hope that you can help:

Can the IPAM role on Windows Server 2012 R2 discover and manage WS2008R2 DHCP clusters, or can it only manage standalone DHCP servers?

If it *can* manage DHCP clusters, should I have the IPAM service discover the cluster service name, or the individual DHCP cluster nodes?

Comment: Update: After fixing firewall rules on the DHCP cluster nodes, I again tried to discover the DHCP cluster with MS IPAM. This time it responded with an "unsupported operating system" message. Thus, it appears that a clustered DHCP service cannot be managed by IPAM. Of course, once a Windows service (e.g. Print or DHCP) is clustered, we must not manage it by connecting directly to a node, so it appears that clustered DHCP is not compatible with Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 IPAM. However, I have yet to find any documentation that confirms or contradicts this finding.

Comment: Answer discovered and posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently IPAM is looking at the operatingSystem attribute on the server's computer account in Active Directory in order to find out whether it is running a supported OS.

In order for Windows Server 2012 IPAM to discover and manage a Windows Server DHCP cluster, you have to open the properties for the AD computer account of the *cluster service name*, go to the Attribute Editor tab, and edit the operatingSystem, operatingSystemVersion, and operatingSystemServicePack attributes to reflect what the DHCP cluster node servers are running.